# How to put screen in a sequence of commands?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, putty, gnu-screen

Hello I'm trying to merge a group of commands in a single line using semicolon ;

pkill screen ; screen ; cd directory ; sudo xx

So basically what I'm trying to do is to kill all open screens then open a new screen and go to a directory and execute a command.

Whenever I try to execute the above-mentioned command it stops at the welcome screen of screen that says press space to continue and the sequence isn't executed..

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
pkill screen ; screen bash -c 'cd directory ; sudo xx'
```

See: [GNU screen in startup screen: multiple commands](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1545643)